# problem with equals() method when used after toString() method

Tags: java, string, equals

When I tried to take two strings as input to a function and check whether they are anagrams, I am getting the wrong output. I have written the following code.

```
    class Solution {
    public boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
        char sArray[] = s.toCharArray();
        char tArray[] = t.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(sArray);
        Arrays.sort(tArray);
        s = sArray.toString();
        t = tArray.toString();
        return s.equals(t);
        
    }
}
```

The sample input I have taken is `s = "anagram" and t = "nagaram"` . When checked, both the char arrays are printing the same value, i.e.

```
sArray is: 
aaagmnr
tArray is: 
aaagmnr
```

But my output seems to be false. Could someone please help me why am I getting such result when I use `equals()` after `toString()`?

Comment: You are most welcome, Shiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion to `String` is incorrect, since arrays don't override the `Object` implementation of `toString()`.

That said, there is no reason to convert the arrays to `String` in order to compare them. You can compare them directly using `Arrays.equals` which will return true `if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal`.

```
char sArray[] = s.toCharArray();
char tArray[] = t.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(sArray);
Arrays.sort(tArray);
return Arrays.equals(sArray,tArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

The below line of code does not convert the char array to String:

```
s = sArray.toString();
t = tArray.toString();
```

This only converts the address into String, in order to convert the Array to String you should use: **Arrays.toString(arrName)**

Now the code will look like this:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
    char sArray[] = s.toCharArray();
    char tArray[] = t.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(sArray);
    Arrays.sort(tArray);
    s = Arrays.toString(sArray);
    t = Arrays.toString(tArray);
    return s.equals(t);  
}
```

Comment: Arrays.toString will return _[a, a, a, g, m, n, r]_ not _aaagmnr_ actually

Comment: Yes, it will return [a, a, a, g, m, n, r] but in case of comparing anagrams it won't effect the logic.

Comment: _in order to convert the Array to String_ this denotes something else actually, doesn't mean string representation of char array with _[_ and separated with ,(comma)

Comment: Still, you can simply use `new String(array)`, to get a plain representation, without additional commas or brackets. Further, the inherited `toString()` method of array produces a class name, followed by @ and the objects *hash code*. This has nothing to do with addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Here, `toString()` on char array called `toString()` method herited from the object class which is :

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So, use  `String.valueOf` to convert a character array to String again

```
s = String.valueOf(sArray);
t = String.valueOf(tArray);
```

Since you need to just compare, you can directly compare the character array using `Arrays.equals()`

```
return Arrays.equals(sArray,tArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the memory address of the sArray and tArray in

```
    s = sArray.toString();
    t = tArray.toString();
```

I suggest that you loop through the value in the array and store it in the String.

```
    for( int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++ )
        str += sArray[i];

    for( int i = 0; i < tArray.length; i++ )
        str2 += tArray[i];
```

Then do comparison like this:

```
return str.equals(str2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `public String(char[] value)` to create a `String` out of the `char[]` e.g.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isAnagram("anagram", "nagaram"));
    }

    public static boolean isAnagram(String s, String t) {
        char sArray[] = s.toCharArray();
        char tArray[] = t.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(sArray);
        Arrays.sort(tArray);
        s = new String(sArray);// Create String out of sArray
        t = new String(tArray);// Create String out of tArray
        return s.equals(t);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

Alternatively, you can use [`String#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char%5B%5D)) to create a `String` out of the `char[]`. There are many more solutions (e.g. comparing the char arrays directly using [`Arrays#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(char%5B%5D,%20char%5B%5D)), comparing each element of one array with those of the other etc.) and I would recommend you try as many as you can for learning purpose.

### What went wrong with your approach?

`sArray.toString()` and `tArray.toString()` return different strings which you could have found out by printing them or by debugging your code. The reason behind this difference is the difference in the hash code of `sArray` and `tArray`. Check [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to learn how to use a debugger to avoid such situations.